# What number comes next?

Tags: number-sequence

> **3, 1, 4, 8, 8, 21, 21, 62, 128, 190, 430, 831, ?**

Find the number that comes next.

**Hint 1:**

> the beginning of the sequence is a hint.

**Hint 2:**

> think n-bonacci, use hint-1 for n.

as **nikki** pointed out my earlier sequence had some mistakes, this is the corrected sequence, i will award the user $(+25)$ bounty for finding it out.

Comment: 3.14 roughly estimates to pi

Comment: that is the first hint @Duck

Comment: (Don't forget that bounty!) :)

Comment: i completely forgot about this riddle, as there were no more activity on it, thanks for the reminder.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Got it

> The n in the n-bonacci varies as the digits in the value of pi
>  The value of pi is 3.14159...
>  Since it starts with 3, take the first 3 digits as is
>  3, 1, 4
>  Next, take the sum of the last 3 digits (coz that's the first digit in the value of pi)
>  3, 1, 4, 8
>  Next, take the sum of the last 1 digit (coz that's the next digit in the value of pi)
>  3, 1, 4, 8, 8
>  Proceed in the following manner to get the next number in the sequence as
>  1545 (value of pi till there is 3.1415926535)

Although

> According to this, the 6th and 7th numbers should be 21, 21

Comment: you got it right, I'll wait for a day to let others come up with some more answers, but you are definitely getting the (✓) tomorrow . also about your confusion, i checked my calculation, it is correct, if you don't figure out how, I'll comment it tomorrow.

Comment: i just re-checked, and turns out you are right, making the changes to the question now. @nikki